# Output the lines that contain closing html tags

Tags: java, regex, string

So I have a txt file that contains the source of an html page (no css, no html5 declaration, no js, just html tags). I must output the index of those lines that contains at least a closing html tag. It should use regex. I know how to look for closing tags, but don't know how to index them. My first idea was to split the source code by the new line character "\n". But then I have to compile the matcher at every line. Is there another method? Thanks!

Comment: you don´t have to compile the matcher every line. also u can match the whole text

Comment: you won todays jackpot ! http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/106261

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or with a scanner:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("</[^>]+>");
Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));

for (int lineNum=1; s.hasNext(); lineNum++) {
      Matcher m = p.matcher(s.next());
            if(m.find()){
              System.out.println(lineNum);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, which reads every line of a file and outputs, if there is a closing tag. I use a BufferedReader to read the file line by line (like explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java) question) and then look, which line contains the pattern.

**UPDATE 1**

As the above comment said you should not use regex to parse your file. If you want to do so, you can e.g. use [JSoup](http://www.jsoup.org). However, if you only want to do what you described in your question, regex is OK.

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class GetClosedTagsOfFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Open the file.
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.html");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        // Compile pattern.
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("</[^>]+>");

        // Read the file.
        String strLine;
        int i = 0;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            i++;

            // Check if there is a closing tag.
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
            if(m.find())
                System.out.println("Line " + i + " contains a closing tag.");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        fis.close();
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not use external java libraries, I have to use regex. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @CalanceaBogdan : My answer does not use any external java libraries. JSoup was only an additional hint.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the source code is one option, you don't have to compile the matcher every line. Another option would be to find the matches, and then start counting newline characters between them.